# python requests <Response [520]>

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, python-requests

I wrote this simple python code:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("http://prnt.sc/")
>>> r.status_code
520
```

i want to download the page at `"http://prnt.sc/"` and i can visualize it correctly using my browser (Mozilla) but with python i really can't.

I already tried changing and randomising my User-Agent using a python module named `fake_useragent`, but nothing changes.

I think this problem may be caused by the fact that python takes a different traceroute than my browser.

If I print `r.text` i get a cloudflare standard page error.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Including a real User-Agent solved it for me:

```
>>> requests.get("http://prnt.sc/", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Platform; Security; OS-or-CPU; Localization; rv:1.4) Gecko/20030624 Netscape/7.1 (ax)'}).status_code
200
```

Comment: The user agent can be much more simple:   `headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome'}`  or  `headers={'User-Agent': 'hello'}` work too.